# C++ string to Json nlohmann

Tags: c++, string, c++11, nlohmann-json

I get a Json variable `j_res`, its content is `"{\"requirement\":\"follow\",\"responseflag\":\"yes\"}"`, I want to get the responseflag and requirement info. I try to convert the message to Json format, and get the `requirement` and `responseflag` value。I tried several ways，but failed.

Way 1:

```
using Json = nlohmann::json;

std::string responseflag = j_res.at("responseflag").dump();
```

error info is `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::out_of_range' what():  [json.exception.out_of_range.403] key 'responseflag' not found`

Way2:

```
using Json = nlohmann::json;

Json j_res2 = Json::parse(j_res.c_str());
std::string requirement = j_res2.at("requirement");
```

error info is

```
error: conversion from ‘nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<>::value_type’ {aka ‘nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<>’} to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} requested
std::string requirement = j_res2.at("requirement");
```

I have remove the leading and trailing double quotes, backslash, it doesn't work.
How can i get the responseflag and requirement info, thanks!

Comment: Apparently, your input JSON seems to have issues. Your code looks like it should work. See https://godbolt.org/z/zaPE9PMsd.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem

```
using Json = nlohmann::json;

rm_double_quote(j_res); // my function
rm_backslash(j_res); // my function
auto j_res2 = Json::parse(j_res.c_str());
std::string str_responseflag = j_res2.at("responseflag").dump();
```

the key is `auto j_res2 = Json::parse(j_res.c_str());`
the type must be `auto`, cannot be `std::string`